# regex pattern not working in pyspark after applying the logic

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data as below:

```
>>> df1.show()
+-----------------+--------------------+
|     corruptNames|       standardNames|
+-----------------+--------------------+
|Sid is (Good boy)|     Sid is Good Boy|
|    New York Life| New York Life In...|
+-----------------+--------------------+
```

So, as per above data I need to apply regex,create a new column and get the data as in the second column i.e `standardNames`. I tried below code:

```
spark.sql("select *, case when corruptNames rlike '[^a-zA-Z ()]+(?![^(]*))' or corruptNames rlike 'standardNames' then standardNames else 0 end as standard from temp1").show()
```

It throws below error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`standardNames`' given input columns: [temp1.corruptNames, temp1. standardNames];
```

Comment: Anyone on this ?

Comment: the column name `temp1. standardNames` has an extra leading space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example without `select sql`. I am assuming you want to create a new column called *standardNames* based on *corruptNames* if the regex pattern is true, otherwise "do something else...".

Note: Your pattern won't compile because you need to escape the second last ) with \.

```
pattern = '[^a-zA-Z ()]+(?![^(]*))' #this won't compile
pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z ()]+(?![^(]*\))' #this will
```

Code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_text = spark.createDataFrame([('Sid is (Good boy)',),('New York Life',)], ('corruptNames',))

pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z ()]+(?![^(]*\))'

df = (df_text.withColumn('standardNames', F.when(F.col('corruptNames').rlike(pattern), F.col('corruptNames'))
             .otherwise('Do something else'))
             .show()
     )

df.show()

#+-----------------+---------------------+
#|     corruptNames|        standardNames|
#+-----------------+---------------------+
#|Sid is (Good boy)|    Do something else|
#|    New York Life|    Do something else|
#+-----------------+---------------------+
```